# How to resize image before creating from Canvas?

Tags: php, base64, image-resizing

I have PHP script to create PNG image from base 64 string from canvas, I need to figure out how to work it, this new PHP script doesn't create resized PNG files.

Reference:

- CanvasPic = Base64 string

Working PHP script but no resize.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('userCanvas/'))
{
    mkdir('userCanvas', 0755, true);
}
else
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $img = $_POST['CanvasPic'];
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'userCanvas/');

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Could not save the file!';
}
?>
```

New script but won't create resized PNG images:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('userCanvas/'))
{
    mkdir('userCanvas', 0755, true);
}
else
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $img = $_POST['CanvasPic'];
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'userCanvas/');

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    $width = 350;
    $height = 250;

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($file);

    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

    if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig)
    {
        $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
    }
    else
    {
        $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    $success = file_put_contents($image_p, $data);
    print $success ? $image_p : 'Could not save the file!';
}
?>
```

Edit: I found errors (skipped line number and URL), I had no idea how to fix these errors.

I found errors, (skipped URL locations and code line):

```
PHP Warning: getimagesize(userCanvas/53bc7c926a606.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
PHP Warning: Division by zero in 
PHP Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions
PHP Warning: imagecreatefrompng(userCanvas/53bc7c926a606.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
PHP Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
PHP Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```